# Using Retrofit to Access an API with key/id

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I haven't really found clear documentation on this, but I was wondering if anyone could point me towards something on using Retrofit (or OKHTTP or something if that's more appropriate) in order to pull down a JSON stream from an API that requires an API ID and API key (example accessing the data from terminal: curl -v -H "app_id:appid" -H "app_key:appkey" -X GET "http://data.leafly.com/strains/blue-dream" ).

I checked over the official documentation on Square's site, but if there's anything else out there that could help me just pull that data down that would be awesome.

Thanks!

---

Final answer

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder= new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint( "http://data.leafly.com/" )
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("app_id", "id");
                    request.addHeader("app_key", "key");
                }
            });

    final RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();

new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LeaflyService service = restAdapter.create(LeaflyService.class);
            final Strain strain = service.data("blue-dream");

            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mText.setText( strain.getDescription() );
                }
            } );
        }
    } ).start();
```

plus the strain model, that just fits the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Retrofit Parameterized @Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478258/android-retrofit-parameterized-headers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send the ID and key, you need to modify the HTTP headers. It appears that you can do this with the [`@Header` annotation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Header.html) in Retrofit.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using the header builder after looking into that annotation.

Answer (score 2):

the answer above didn`t work for me, here is my solution:

> ```
>     RestAdapter.Builder adapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
>             .setEndpoint(BACKEND_URL).setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
>                     request.addQueryParam("apikey", apiKey);
>                 }
>             });
>     service = adapterBuilder.build().create(BackendInterface.class);
> ```

```
@POST("/getall")
void getIdeaList( Callback<GetAllIdeaResponse> callback);
```

Comment: based on documentation, this is like using @Query("apiKey") String apiKey in the interface, as a parameter of the method.