# Android novice needs help on android server interaction

Tags: android, http, curl, php-curl

I have a backend app in Django for which we need to send some data by the frontend. Using cURL with php we do it in the following way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<body>
    <?php
        $ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token");
        $s = 'some string';
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization: Bearer facebook '."$s"));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURL_RETURNTRANSFER, False);

        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

where $s is a variable. I want to know what can be the equivalent code in android to implement the same thing.

Comment: Please present a full SSCCE of your PHP that you want equivalent Java for. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Great.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a tool like [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for the job. So have a MyService interface as such:

```
public interface MyService {    
    @Headers("Authorization: Bearer facebook")
    @GET("/auth/convert-token")
    SomeResponseObject auth();
}
```

And you'd build it and call it:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000")
            .build();

MyService service = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);

SomeResponseObject response = service.auth();
```

Edit: To add a string variable, you'll have to use RequestInterceptor as explained here: [Android Retrofit Parameterized @Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478258/android-retrofit-parameterized-headers)

Comment: Nowhere in your code I see a addition of the string to the header. @Jay Ammar

Comment: Answer updated with how to incorporrate string. @ApurvaJha

Comment: If you could please look at this post as well and tell me the solution then I would be highly grateful to you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821112/header-not-getting-set-properly-in-android-retrofit

@JayAmmar