# Retrofit - is there an `@Path` equivalent for headers?

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2

Or how else would you write something like this?

```
@Headers(
        "$CONTENT_TYPE:${BodyContentType.JSON}",
        "$AUTHORIZATION:Bearer {jwt}"
)
@POST("/some/where")
fun something(@Path("jwt")jwt:String, @Body somethingRequest:JsonObject):Call<JsonObject>
```

(which results in

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "/some/where" does not contain "{jwt}". (parameter #1)

)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Retrofit Parameterized @Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478258/android-retrofit-parameterized-headers)

Comment: Try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885004/6235974

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Header.html
there is the `@Header` annotation.

So in your case it would be:

```
fun something(@Header("jwt")jwt:String, @Body somethingRequest:JsonObject):Call<JsonObject>
```

Comment: There are two issues with the `@Header` annotation. One: It's impossible to add multiple headers with the same name. Two: It requires that the full header value is provided as a string value. So in your example, the `"jwt"` needs be changed to `"authorization"` and the `jwt:String` must ACTUALLY contain `"Bearer " + jwtToken`

Comment: As stated in the documentation, the Header annotation also supports List and array types, i.e: fun something(@Header("jwt") jwt: List<String>,...)

Regarding the second problem, yes, it think there is no support for templating. You would have to parse this yourself.